# Sitecore Page Editor components jumping to the first position

Tags: sitecore, page-editor, sitecore7.2

I'm using Sitecore 7.2. I have a center column placeholder where users can select from a list of components using the Page Editor, set data source and edit the content of the data source.

I'm experiencing a strange problem where if I have components on this placeholder and if I try to add other components below it they jump to the first position in the placeholder. I'm not sure what is going here and looking to see if someone else has come across this same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do your components have some align styles? 
e.g. "float:right;"

Comment: None of the components have a float. The elements inside the components do though.

Comment: You should determine is it client-side problem or server side. Look on HTML DOM if order of components is correct. If order is incorrect you should look on pipelines that correspond for parsing rendering xml.

Comment: what is the order of the components when you check the presentation details of the item from the content editor?

Comment: The newly added component is anywhere it wishes to be in the presentation details. Only if I move it to the end in the presentation details does it work as expected.

Comment: @Gabbar Do you use Sitecore MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: MVC for this project.

Comment: @Gabbar, if it is MVC - you can try to look at ProcessXMLBasedLayoutDefinition processor. Probably something goes wrong there.